# Calculate the average budget of all movies in the data set

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
movies = [
     ("Titanic", 20000000),
     ("Dracula", 9000000),
     ("James Bond", 4500000),
     ("Pirates of the Caribbean: On Stranger Tides", 379000000),
     ("Avengers: Age of Ultron", 365000000),
     ("Avengers: Endgame", 356000000),
     ("Incredibles 2", 200000000)
 ]
```

Want to Calculate the average budget of all movies in the data set.
Any suggestion ?

Comment: what have you tried? The basic algorithm should be: creating new variable to hold the total, then do a for/while loop, then lastly divide the total with number of element

Comment: Add up all the movie budgets and divide by the number of movies.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: @JohnGordon i was getting TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing `movies` is a normal Python List and that you would like to get the average cost in **Dollars**:

```
movies = [
     ("Titanic", 20000000),
     ("Dracula", 9000000),
     ("James Bond", 4500000),
     ("Pirates of the Caribbean: On Stranger Tides", 379000000),
     ("Avengers: Age of Ultron", 365000000),
     ("Avengers: Endgame", 356000000),
     ("Incredibles 2", 200000000)
 ]

totalCost = 0
totalMovies = 0

for movie, price in movies:
    totalCost += price
    totalMovies +=1
    
print (f"The average cost per movie is {totalCost/totalMovies:.2f}$")
```

The line `{totalCost/totalMovies:.2f}` is inserting the computation in-line making use of the Python `F strings` while selecting two decimal values (`.2f`)

Hope everything was clear!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with an `accumulator` variable to hold the sum and a `for` loop:

Here is an example:

```py
movies = [
    ("Titanic", 20000000),
    ("Dracula", 9000000),
    ("James Bond", 4500000),
    ("Pirates of the Caribbean: On Stranger Tides", 379000000),
    ("Avengers: Age of Ultron", 365000000),
    ("Avengers: Endgame", 356000000),
    ("Incredibles 2", 200000000)
]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Declarative
    accumulator = 0
    for (_, budget) in movies:
        accumulator += budget
    print(accumulator / len(movies))
```

On the `for` statement, I'm unwrapping both items from the tuple into two new variables: `_` and `budget`. Using an `_` is a common practice to declare that you don't need to use that variable.

The last line prints the average, calculated by dividing over the length of the list.

Comment: Thanks Its working . Can you explain the if part ?

Comment: Sure. We can use an `if __name__ == "__main__"` block to allow or prevent parts of code from being run when the modules are imported. The `if` block of code will only be run if you call the module with python, but not if you import it from another module.

Answer (score -1):

The normal approach for calculating averages would work here. Something along the lines of

```
total = 0
for movie, budget in movies:
  total += budget

average = total / movies.length
```

should do the trick for you here.